# How to unpack this generator

Tags: python

I have written code for the [zig-zag problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/) on LeetCode. The function works correctly when I use a multi-line for loop. However the current `print` statement outputs a generator function. I tried using the `*` key but it didn't seem to work.

How do I unpack this generator function?

The output I want is a string, not a list.

Thanks

```
def zigzag (word, num_rows):
    array = [] 
    for _ in range(num_rows):
        array.append([])
    increasing = 1
    array_index = 0
    word_index = 0

    while word_index < len(word):
        if increasing: 
            array[array_index].append(word[word_index])
            array_index +=1 
            word_index +=1
        else:
            array[array_index].append(word[word_index])
            array_index -=1 
            word_index +=1 
        if array_index == -1 and increasing == 0: 
            increasing = 1
            array_index = 1
        if array_index == num_rows and increasing == 1:
            increasing = 0
            array_index = num_rows - 2 
    return array



if __name__ == "__main__":
    word = "PAYPALISHIRING"
    num_rows = 4
    print ("".join(line) for line in zigzag(word, num_rows))
```

Comment: For future references, please include a desired output in your question. Asking question without telling people what you want as an output is simply a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Sorry. I'll do that next time

Answer (score 1):

One line for-loop:

```
print ("".join(line for array in zigzag(word, num_rows) for line in array))

# PINALSIGYAHRPI
```